# Being able to display an image from MySQL database

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

What I'm currently trying to do is display an image from the database in which I've saved an image into. The problem is that the image comes up blank on the home page, when it should be showing the image.

What I tried was asking for assistance and ended up with creating a controller which would display the image by doing some conversion which will be shown below

My Controller

```
@GetMapping("/display/image/{id}")
public ResponseEntity<byte[]> displayItemImage(@PathVariable int id) {
    Item item = itemService.findItemById(id);
    byte[] image = item.getImage();
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG);
    return new ResponseEntity<>(image, headers, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

The thymeleaf

```
<div class="category-1">
    <h2>Headwear</h2>
    <div class="image-container" th:each="clothing : ${clothingItems}">
        <img th:src="@{'display/image/' + ${clothing.id}}">
    </div>

</div>
```

Expected result was hoping to be like this from the database [image: Expected]

The actual result was a blank image (Just showing an image icon with an empty white box)
It wouldn't end up showing and I was told that my server-side code is fine and it could be the way I'm saving it into the database

HTML form with thymeleaf to save the result

```
<form class="contact-form" method="POST" th:action="@{/crafts}" th:object="${item}">

    <div class="button-group">
        <input type="radio" name="category-choice" id="choice-1" th:field="*{category}" th:value="${clothing}">
        <input type="radio" name="category-choice" id="choice-2" th:field="*{category}" th:value="${cosmetics}">
        <input type="radio" name="category-choice" id="choice-3" th:field="*{category}" th:value="${celebration}">
        <input type="radio" name="category-choice" id="choice-4" th:field="*{category}" th:value="${other}">
    </div>

    <div class="label-group">
        <label for="choice-1" class="label-1">Clothing</label>
        <label for="choice-2" class="label-2">Cosmetics</label>
        <label for="choice-3" class="label-3">Celebration</label>
        <label for="choice-4" class="label-4">Other</label>
    </div>

    <input type="file" id="fileUpload" accept="image/*" th:field="*{image}">


    <div id="description-field">
        <label for="description">Description</label>
        <textarea name="userText" id="description" cols="50" rows="10" placeholder="Describe what you have made..."
                  required th:field="*{text}"></textarea>
    </div>

    <button type="submit">Submit</button>

</form>
```

Controllers used for this

```
@GetMapping("/crafts/new")
public String createPost(Model model){

    Item item = new Item();

    Category clothing = categoryService.findCategoryById(1);
    Category cosmetics = categoryService.findCategoryById(2);
    Category celebration = categoryService.findCategoryById(3);
    Category other = categoryService.findCategoryById(4);

    model.addAttribute("item", item);

    model.addAttribute("clothing", clothing.getId());
    model.addAttribute("cosmetics", cosmetics.getId());
    model.addAttribute("celebration", celebration.getId());
    model.addAttribute("other", other.getId());

    return "add-form";



}
```

```
@PostMapping("/crafts")
public String saveItem(@ModelAttribute("item") Item item){
    itemService.saveItem(item);
    return "redirect:/home";
}
```

And MySQL

```
CREATE TABLE categories(
   id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    category VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO categories (category) VALUES
 ("Clothing"),
 ("Cosmetics"),
 ("Celebration"),
 ("Other");

CREATE TABLE posts(
   id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
   img BLOB NOT NULL,
   post TEXT,
    category_id INT,
    FOREIGN KEY(category_id) REFERENCES categories(id)
);

CREATE TABLE authorities(
   id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    authority VARCHAR(50)
);

INSERT INTO authorities(authority) VALUES
   ("ROLE_USER"),
    ("ROLE_ADMIN");

CREATE TABLE users(
   username VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    password VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    role_id INT,
    FOREIGN KEY(role_id) REFERENCES authorities(id)
);

INSERT INTO users(username, password, role_id) VALUES
("Admin", "password", 2);

CREATE TABLE contact(
   id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(100),
    email VARCHAR(255),
   body TEXT
);
```

An image within the database would look like this below

[image: Image within MySQL]

Item class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "posts")
public class Item {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "post")
    private String text;

    @Lob
    @Column(name = "img")
    private byte[] image;

    @OneToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.DETACH,
                        CascadeType.MERGE,
                        CascadeType.PERSIST,
                        CascadeType.REFRESH})
    @JoinColumn(name = "category_id")
    private Category category;


    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    public byte[] getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage(byte[] image) {
        this.image = image;
    }

    public Category getCategory() {
        return category;
    }

    public void setCategory(Category category) {
        this.category = category;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Item{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", text='" + text + '\'' +
                ", image=" + Arrays.toString(image) +
                ", category=" + category +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Item Repository which extends JPARepository

```
@Repository
public interface ItemRepository extends JpaRepository<Item, Integer> {

    @Query("FROM Item WHERE category_id = 1")
    List<Item> findAllHeadwear();

    @Query("FROM Item WHERE category_id = 2")
    List<Item> findAllCosmetics();

    @Query("FROM Item WHERE category_id = 3")
    List<Item> findAllCelebration();

    @Query("FROM Item WHERE category_id = 4")
    List<Item> findAllOther();

}
```

Along with the Service which is using the repository

```
@Override
public void saveItem(Item item) {
    itemRepository.save(item);
}
```

Comment: Start by doing a "view source" on the web page that is showing the blank image.  Look at the `src` for the `img` element.  Is the `src` URL correct?

Comment: Yes it is doing it correctly <img src="display/image/1"> this is the correct id

Comment: Next.  Use your browser's web tools to find out what response it is getting when it attempts to fetch the image URL.

Comment: What's the definition of the item class and what does the saveItem method do?

Comment: Status code is 200 OK, the only thing it seems to say for me is that its missing is that there's no title attribute, so I added it and its the same result

Comment: I'll add the saveItem!

Comment: Next.  Use your browser to fetch the image URL explicitly.  Does it display an image?   What does the browser say that its document type (content type) is?  Is that correct?

Comment: (Hint: this is how you solve the problem.  Work through things methodically to try to figure out what is actually going wrong.  Debugging 101.)

Comment: Content type is image/png, as for fetching the image it will show a small white box. I did try switching the content type to MediaType.IMAGE_PNG (if that's what you're going for), however it still wouldn't display unless I'm missing something

Comment: You do not store the image's actual content type. According to your code, all images are assumed to be jpeg. Did you upload jpegs or did you use different type of images?

Comment: Used png/ jpeg / jpg different types of images to see if it will display, I have tried switching to png and uploading png images and it will not show if you are talking about the MediaType

Comment: Pngs would not render because of incorrect content type. You have to store the images' mime type in the database and set the content type header accordingly or you must restrict the file types you can upload to jpeg. You do need to check if the image controller returns the byte content from the database as well.

Comment: storing their mime type? Also I have tried restricting file types to png and switched MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG to MediaType.IMAGE_PNG if that's what you are referring to.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types

Comment: Would it say the images mime type within the database? because for me it will say BLOB, if so, where can I look more into storing the images mime type

Comment: BLoB is the column's data tyoe, not mime type! Mime type appliy to http coomunication (please read the linked documentation). You need to store the mime type in a separate field (varchar) or restrict the mime types you can upload to one.